# Gutenberg - get values from server side

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Im search information about it ago several hours but I cannot find a solve.

I have a plugin with a global functions called "get_regions()":

```
$all_regions = get_regions();
// array('region-1', 'region-2', 'region-3', 'region-4')
```

Then I need put those values in a select in my block Gutenberg. I have this code in my edit function **and it works**!

```
edit: function(props) {

    return el(Fragment, {},
        el(InspectorControls, {},
            el(PanelBody, { title: __( 'Target Countries Settings') },
                el(PanelRow, { className: 'components-base-control'},
                    el(SelectControl, {
                            label: __('Include Regions'),
                            multiple : 'true',
                            options : [
                                    { label: __( 'region-1' ), value: 'region-1' },
                                    { label: __( 'region-2' ), value: 'region-2' }
                            ]
                        },
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

But it has static values, I need the options in "SelectControl" has those values from the function `get_regions()`.

How can I get this values from side server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had use the plan B.

I used `wp_localize_script()` to send this values.

Regards